# CSV import to MySQL brings question marks

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am trying to import a .csv to a MySQL table but it seems that Greek characters do not display correctly.

the query is the following

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/book2.csv' 
INTO TABLE mid_prod
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The collation of the table is UTF-8

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the encoding of the CSV file? Is it UTF-8, too, or something else? Also, what is the **character set** of the database? Is that UTF-8, too?

Comment: the csv comes from an excel file.  I saved it by choosing the option to make it utf8.  But here is an issue.  When i open it from openoffice and then try to save it as csv it says that the collation is Greek(Windows 1253).

Answer (score 0):

1. Connection encoding, must be one of Greek or UTF. Try utf8: run `SET NAMES utf8;` query before loading data.
2. Table's encoding doesn't means that column has the same encoding. Check column's encoding, you can find this info using SHOW CREATE TABLE command or look at `information_schema`.`columns` table.
3. And, of course, file encoding.